# Help testing a case standard object trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I need help testing a trigger written against the Case Standard Object. It keeps failing at 74% and I don't understand why? Here's what I have... any & all advice is appreciated.

TRIGGER

```
trigger ResponseCaseUpdate on Case (after update) 
{
    Map<ID, case> oldmap=new Map<ID, case>();
    List<FeedItem> fItem=new List<FeedItem>();
    for (case o : trigger.new)
    {
        if(o.Response__c!=System.Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Response__c)
        {           
            FeedItem f=new FeedItem();
            f.ParentId=o.Id;
            f.Title=o.contactID;
            f.Type='TextPost';             
            f.Body='Previous Entry: '+ '\N ' +
                   System.Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Response__c+ '\N ' +
                   'New Response: '+ '\N ' +o.Response__c;                            
            f.CreatedById=o.LastModifiedById;
            fItem.add(f);                                  
        }
    }    
    insert fItem;                    
}
```

TEST

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ResponseCaseUpdate_Test{

    private static testmethod void ResponseCaseUpdate_Test()
    {
        Case testCase = new Case(Response__c = 'Testing...1-2-3...');
        insert testCase;
        testCase = [select Id, Response__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :testCAse.Id];
        System.assertEquals(testCase.Response__c, 'Testing...1-2-3...');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test needs to update and change the Response__c field in the process as the trigger is "after update".

Comment: n.b. (1) the `System.Trigger` can be simplified to `Trigger`; (2) your `oldMap` variable is not used and can be removed; your assert should be seeing whether a `FeedItem` is created, not verifying that the Case was created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments above, your trigger only enters the loop if the case is updated and the field has changed so you need to be doing that in your test case. In fact, you should be doing an insert and verifying that the feed item was NOT created as well (negative test case)

With that in mind:

```
   @isTest
    public with sharing class ResponseCaseUpdate_Test{

        private static testmethod void ResponseCaseInsert_Test()
        {
            Case testCase = new Case(Response__c = 'Testing...1-2-3...');
            insert testCase;
            Feeditem[] result = [Select ID From FeedItem Where ParentID = :testcase.id];
            system.assertEquals(true,result.isEmpty(),'A feed item was created on insert');
        }

        private static testmethod void ResponseCaseUpdate_Test()
        {
           Case testCase = new Case();
           insert testCase;
           testCase.Response__c = 'Testing...1-2-3...';
           update testCase;
           Feeditem[] result = [Select ID, body From FeedItem Where ParentID = :testcase.id];
           system.assertEquals(false,result.isEmpty(),'A feed item was NOT created on update');
          system.assertEquals(true,result[0].body.contains('Testing...1-2-3...'));


   }


}
```

Comment: When I deploy into production, I still get: Details: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 74%, at least 75% test coverage is required.

Comment: @Rocket_Izz - What is the coverage for THIS trigger and ONLY this trigger? Other classes are a different issue and have nothing to do with this trigger / test class. Let ensure this trigger is covered sufficiently first, then tackle the rest.

Comment: Test coverage is 15/15 lines. So, it's the overall code coverage of our production environment that's failing...which I don't understand. If you have to pass to get in, how did so many failing pieces of code make it in?

Comment: There are ways to save code directly to production that may not have a test class and can skew the overall code. Another issue could be that tests were using existing data and written poorly and thus no longer execute all the code but do not fail. Lots of reason, usually due to shortcuts and test methods written to simply cover lines

Comment: Ok? Moving code into production without a passing test result? That kinda defeats the purpose. Since the failing code is from vendor's apps, I'm assuming that's the bypass...or at least one way. Anyhow, we're contacting them in an effort to clean up the mess. Hopefully they address this matter in a timely fashion b/c we're about to take on another huge vendor project (gulp). Thanks :)

Comment: @Rocket_Izz - Managed package tests / classes DO NOT count toward your individual org code coverage so that is not the issue. (Unless, their package is causing tests in your org to fail)